# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE ignoring last entry

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load data exported from SQL Server into MySQL using the command:

```
mysql databasename -e"LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/calendar.txt' INTO TABLE events FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (id,catid,title,state,created,publish_up,publish_down,event_status,alldayevent,approved,UnSpecifiedEndTime);"
```

The file calendar.txt is of the following format:

```
7300    1143    'item 1'      1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 17:30:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       '1'
7301    1143    'item 2'      1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 17:30:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       '1'
7302    1143    'item 3'        1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 17:55:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       '1'
7303    1143    'item 4'      1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 19:15:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       1
7304    61      'item 5'        1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 19:30:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       1
7644    1053    'item 6'  1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-8 00:00:00       2012-1-8 00:00:00       Pending 1       1       1
7305    1143    'item 7'    1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-9 00:00:00       2012-1-9 00:00:00       Pending 1       1       1
7306    1056    'item 8'      1       2012-01-03 15:30:14     2012-1-9 8:10:00        2012-1-9 00:00:00       Pending 0       1       1
```

The column UnSpecifiedEndTime isn't being correctly populated, if you view it in phpmyadmin after an import it looks blank, in order to make it populate you have to add an additional tab and field, this seems like a field count issue but I can't spot anything and all other fields seem to be being populated in the right order.

The end field being enclosed with quotes doesn't make any difference, the field type I'm trying to insert into is defined as:

```
enum('0', '1')
```

Any help much appreciated

SQL to create the table in question is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `adresse_info` varchar(120) NOT NULL default '',
  `contact_info` varchar(120) NOT NULL default '',
  `extra_info` varchar(240) NOT NULL default '',
  `color_bar` varchar(8) NOT NULL default '',
  `useCatColor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `state` tinyint(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mask` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_by_alias` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `checked_out` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `images` text NOT NULL,
  `reccurtype` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `reccurday` varchar(4) NOT NULL default '',
  `reccurweekdays` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `reccurweeks` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `archived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `access` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `event_status` enum('Pending','Complete','Postponed','Cancelled') NOT NULL,
  `postponed_child_eventid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Editor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reason_to_change` text NOT NULL,
  `alldayevent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `UnSpecifiedEndTime` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
  `notice_is_holiday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `notice_spdesk_ticker` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `catid` (`catid`),
  KEY `publish_down` (`publish_down`),
  KEY `publish_up` (`publish_up`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7645 ;
```

Comment: It could be helpful to know the table structure and columns type. Please add the "CREATE TABLE..." to your post.

Comment: You also can use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) tool which uses LOAD DATA INFILE too but has nicer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field separator in your file, in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement it is a TAB symbol, but in your example (file calendar.txt) they are white spaces.

Also, change

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' to FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

and

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' to LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```